# Telerik Javascript error on unload page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I am using Telerik controls in my Asp.net web application. I am facing javascript error on unload page:

> Unable to set value of the property '_events': Object is null or undefined

I am facing this issue when i have merged/combined my asp.net website with MVC4.
I have searched on Google but unable to find any solution.

Edit:

I found problem:

When RadComboBox is empty then this error is occurred. RadComboBox Load data at runtime (when user clicks on it).

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which telerik controls are you using? What is their version?
If you are using the AjaxControlToolkit in the same project, try removing it (delete the assembly and the reference, rebuild) and see if this helps.

Comment: Hi I haved added issue...can you please look into it?

Comment: Again, which Telerik controls are you using? Are they the MVC extensions? If they are the AJAX controls you may have issues with MVC environments.
What is the versio, does the latest fix the issue?
Are you using the AjaxControlToolkit? It messes up event handlers and MS AJAX.

Comment: I have resolved it. It was version issue. I have added updated dll. Thanks for your response